# Mocked method not returning correct value when passed to class under test

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to test a method which takes an object as its input parameter and calls a method that returns an array, `getArray()`, on it. I want to mock this object using **Google Mock** and tell it to return a particular array when called. Otherwise, I am relying on the implementation of the object's class to be correct.

I have mocked the object to be passed to the method under test like so:

```
class MockInputClass : public InputClass {
    public:
        MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(getArray, std::array<uint8_t, 4>());
};
```

My test is as follows:

```
TEST(ClassUnderTest, methodToTest_DoesWhatIWant) {
    MockInputClass mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, getArray())
        .WillRepeatedly(
            Return(std::array<uint8_t, 4>({1, 2, 3, 4}))
        );
    std::cout << "Called in test: " << mock.getArray()[0] << std::endl;
    ClassUnderTest obj;
    obj.methodToTest(mock);
}
```

In my `classundertest.h`, I have defined `methodToTest` like so:

```
auto methodToTest(InputClass &input) -> void {
    std::cout << "Called in class under test: " << input.getArray()[0] << std::endl;
}
```

If I run the test, the output is:

```
Called in test: 1
Called in class under test: 0
```

For some reason, once I have passed my mocked object to the class being tested, it no longer seems to return what I told it to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is getArray() virtual in InputClass? Otherwise your mocked method will not be called. Since methodToTest takes a InputClass& and not a InputClassMock.

Comment: @warsac Yeah that was it. I can see now why it would need to be declared virtual. However I'm a little unsure what's happening when the mocked method is called and getArray() isn't virtual. Is it calling the concrete implementation of getArray() on a default constructed instance of InputClass?

Comment: @MattRead No! What makes you think that a new instance is created? The `InputClass` parameter is passed via reference. Since the method is not virtual in `InputClass`, base class version of `getArray` is called from the mock object. Mock class has this method because it inherits from `InputClass`, it's that simple.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic I probably worded that badly. The reason I ask is that the the base class implementation of `getArray` returns a member variable of `InputClass`, which obviously wasn't explicitly initialized when my Mock object was initialized. So I'm assuming the member array of `InputClass` was inherited by `MockInputClass` and was by default set to an array of zeroes, which would explain the output?

Comment: @Matt Read Yes, the base class impl of getArray will be called. If InputClass constructor does not instansiate the returned member explicitly a default constructed std::Array<uint8_t, 4> will be returned. I'm not sure if that is guaranteed to be 0s or if it could be just random memory.